# Wso2 IS 5.0.0 Google SSO with username

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I have configured the google as SAML based Service provider. 
I would like to login using username and would like to use email address in google assertion 
Can i configure this in WSO2 identity server 5.0.0 version ?

Regards,
Gaurav

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure about your requirement. You can login to Google by providing username and password of the user store. You can add email address to SAML assertion as attribute statement or as the subject identifier.  Here you need to choose the desired claim uri, for email it would be `http://wso2.org/claims/emailaddress`   More detail can be found [here](http://soasecurity.org/2014/04/30/open-source-saml2-sso-identity-provider/)